# Make a Testimonial Scroller Stay on the Screen Before Fading Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a testimonial scroller that shows one testimonial, fades out, shows the next, fades out, and returns to the first.

My issue is that after the fade in animation, the fade out animation begins immediately. It doesn't give enough time for someone to read it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function doFade() {
        $("#one").fadeIn(6000,function() {
            $("#one").fadeOut(6000).delay(3000);
            setTimeout(fadeTwo,6000);
        });
    }

    function fadeTwo() {
        $("#two").fadeIn(6000,function() {
            $("#two").fadeOut(6000).delay(3000);
            setTimeout(fadeThree,6000);
        });
    }

    function fadeThree() {
        $("#three").fadeIn(4000,function() {
            $("#three").fadeOut(6000).delay(3000);
            setTimeout(doFade,6000);
        });
    }
    doFade();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's delay function will only delay functions that are called *after* it in the chain, so it is having no effect on your code. [Delay docs](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

You need to use it before the call to fadeOut, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function doFade() {
        $("#one").fadeIn(6000,function() {
            setTimeout(fadeTwo,6000);
        })
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut(6000);
    }

    function fadeTwo() {
        $("#two").fadeIn(6000,function() {
            setTimeout(fadeThree,6000);
        })
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut(6000);
    }

    function fadeThree() {
        $("#three").fadeIn(6000,function() {
            setTimeout(doFade,6000);
        })
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut(6000);
    }
    doFade();
});
```

Edit:

You are currently setting a timeout to execute the next function, within the complete callback of fadeIn.  This is a bit confusing to my mind, and I think it is simpler and clearer to do something like the following.  In addition, there is no reason to define the three functions within the ready function - it is personal preference but I like to keep the amount of code within a callback to a minimum, such as...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doFade();
});

function doFade() {
    setTimeout(fadeTwo,12000);
    $("#one").fadeIn(6000).delay(3000).fadeOut(6000);
}

function fadeTwo() {
    setTimeout(fadeThree,12000);
   $("#two").fadeIn(6000).delay(3000).fadeOut(6000);
}

function fadeThree() {
    setTimeout(doFade,12000);
    $("#three").fadeIn(6000).delay(3000).fadeOut(6000);
}
```

Edit 2:

In further effort to reduce the amount we repeat ourselves, we can extract the whole animation sequence into a function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doFade();
});

function fadeInThenOut(element) {
    element.fadeIn(6000).delay(3000).fadeOut(6000);
}

function doFade() {
    setTimeout(fadeTwo,12000);
    fadeInThenOut($("#one"));
}

function fadeTwo() {
    setTimeout(fadeThree,12000);
   fadeInThenOut($("#two"));
}

function fadeThree() {
    setTimeout(doFade,12000);
    fadeInThenOut($("#three"));
}
```

Edit 3:

At this point we probably notice how similar our three functions are, and want some way to reduce *that* repetitiveness.  So we could use recursion, and just change which element we pass in each time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doFade();
});

function doFade(elementNumber) {
    const elementNumber = elementNumber < testimonialElements.length ? elementNumber : 0;

    setTimeout(doFade(elementNumber + 1),12000);
    $('#' + testimonialElements[elementNumber]).fadeIn(6000).delay(3000).fadeOut(6000);
}

var testimonialElements = ["one","two","three"];
```

While this solution may lose something in readability and simplicity, the great advantage is that when you add a fourth testimonial, you don't need to write a function to handle it.  All you would do is change the testimonialElements array to include the new element id.